# gdb list step into targets

Tags: debugging, gdb

Is there a way in gdb to get a list of functions you could step into when the current line is composed of several function calls like `foo(computeParam1(), computeParam2(), computeParam3())`?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Perhaps you are looking for the `nexti` command, which moves to the next instruction, with a function call being considered a single instruction, or the `stepi` command which single steps an instruction including into a new function call. If you use `stepi` then you should know about `finish` which continues the current function until it finishes, not to be confused with `return`!